# Routing in express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have structure like this:

```
server.ts
routes/
    index.ts
    homeRoute.ts
```

In `server.ts`:

```
let app = Express();
app.use(router);
```

In `routes/index.ts`:

```
const routes = Router();
export default function router() {
  routes.use('/home', homeRoute);
}
```

In `routes/homeRoutes.ts`

```
let homeRouter = Express.Router();

export default function homeRoute(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  console.log('home route');
  homeRouter.get('/home', function);
  next();
}
```

My problem is when i call `http://localhost:3000`, it run to `index.ts` file ( I console.log some things so I know that), however it don't execute my `routes.use('/home', homeRoute)`. 
I don't know why it is. Please help me fix it.

Comment: Are you aware that you should go to `http://localhost:3000/home/home`? If it is not what you intend to do, replace the `/home` with `/` in your `homeRouter.get` in other to access it at `http://localhost:3000/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand how import and export works. Ideally your code should be something like this.

server.ts

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {routes} from './routes';
const app = express();
routes(app);
```

routes/index.ts

```
import {homeRoute} from './homeRoutes';
export const routes = (app) => {
  homeRoute(app);
}
```

routes/homeRoutes.ts

```
export const homeRoute = (app) => {
  app.get('/home', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('home');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Muthukumar . Can you tell me what `routes = (app)` mean ( in index.ts file)?

Comment: It exports a function called routes, which take a single parameter app. This function is called from server.ts to initialize the routes